# unordered_map maxes out unique keys only with 16 character strings

Tags: c++, hash, key, unordered-map

This code generates a random 16-character string using only A,C,T,G. It then checks whether this sequence is in the hash (unordered_map), and if not, inserts it and points to a dummy placeholder.

In its current form, it hangs at datact=16384 when the 'for i loop' requires 20000 iterations, despite the fact that there are 4^16 strings with ACTG.

But.. if the string length is changed to 8, 9, 10, 11.. to 15, or 17, 18.. it correctly iterates to 20000. Why does unordered_map refuse to hash new sequences, but only when those sequences are 16 characters long?

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string funnelstring;

    srand ( time(NULL) );

    const int buffersize=10000;
    int currentsize=buffersize;

    int datact=0;

    vector <unsigned int> ctarr(buffersize);

    vector <char> nuc(4);
    nuc[0]='A';
    nuc[1]='C';
    nuc[2]='T';
    nuc[3]='G';

    unordered_map <string,unsigned int*> location;

    unsigned int sct;
    sct=1;

    for (int i=0;i<20000; i++)
    {
        do
        {
            funnelstring="";
            for (int i=0; i<16; i++)
            {   // generate random 16 nucleotide sequence
                funnelstring+=nuc[(rand() % 4)];
            }
        } while (location.find(funnelstring) != location.end()); //asks whether this key has been assigned

        ctarr[datact]=sct;
        location[funnelstring]=&ctarr[datact]; //assign current key to point to data count
        datact++;
        cout << datact << endl;

        if (datact>=currentsize)
        {
            ctarr.resize(currentsize+buffersize);
            currentsize+=buffersize;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think the title is misleading. I am pretty sure this has *nothing* to do with `unordered_map` as such. Where do you get the idea that "it refuses to hash new sequences"? I would point at the PRNG as the most likely culprit.

Comment: OK, very interesting. The funny thing is I'm trying to reproduce an almost identical bug but where the sequences aren't randomly generated. It looks like I accidentally introduced a new problem in this code, sorry for the false advertising. What's the protocol here? Consider this sub-question solved, and possibly open a new one with the "complete" problem?

Comment: Yeah, although you should try to narrow it down as far as you can, i.e. provide a code sample that reproduces your problem but doesn't have unnecessary detail (for the record, I think your sample for *this* question is pretty good in that respect).

Comment: You could of course use `"AAACATAGCACCCTCGTATCTTTGGAGCGTGG"[2*(rand()%16]` to fetch two bases at a time. This uses less random numbers and uses more random bits from each number. Even so you should still get a better RNG than your current one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @us2012 said, the problem is your PRNG, and the poor randomness in the lower order bits. Here's a relevant quote:

> In Numerical Recipes in C: The Art of Scientific Computing (William H. Press, Brian P. Flannery, Saul A. Teukolsky, William T. Vetterling; New York: Cambridge University Press, 1992 (2nd ed., p. 277)), the following comments are made:
>
> "If you want to generate a random integer between 1 and 10, you should always do it by using high-order bits, as in

```
j = 1 + (int) (10.0 * (rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0)));
```

> and never by anything resembling

```
j = 1 + (rand() % 10);
```

> (which uses lower-order bits)."

Also, as others have pointed out, you can also use a better, more modern RNG.

Comment: That quote should be considered in context. **IF** your PRNG is from the eighties, then the advice holds. As us2012 points out, C++11 has `<random>` which is far better. In particular it has better PRNG's and `std::uniform_int_distribution`.

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is very likely your random number generator, i.e. the sequence of random numbers from the PRNG became periodic (`mod 4`) too quickly (most random number generators really produce *pseudo*-random numbers, hence the name PRNG). Therefore, your `do...while` loop never quits as it is unable to find a new nucleotide sequence with the random numbers provided.

Two fixes I can think of:

- Instead of generating random numbers `mod 4`, generate them `mod 4^length` and extract the bit pairs, `00 -> A, 01 -> G, ...`
- Use a better PRNG, like `std::mersenne_twister_engine`.

(Disclaimer: I'm not an expert on random numbers. Don't rely on this advice for mission-critical systems, cryptographic requirements, etc.)